# Java8 HashMap inside another Hashmap, how to find salary sum

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a structure as shown below. I am trying to calculate the sum of all employee salaries. I would like to use Java streams. Could someone please explain how I can achieve this?

`Employee` has a `getSalary` method.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Employee>> mainMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Employee> emplmap1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Employee> emplmap2 = new HashMap<>();

emplmap1.put("A",empl1);
emplmap1.put("B",empl2);
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `flatMap`, which can accept an element that's a stream and then flattens all the streams into one stream, and a `map` which converts elements in a stream to different elements:

```
double salary = mainMap.values().stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())
        .map(Employee::getSalary)
        .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
        .sum();

System.out.println("Total salary: " + salary);
```

`mainMap.values().stream()` will return a stream of `mainMap`'s values (the maps). We `flatMap` the stream by turning every element (a map) to a stream of that map's values. Then we get the salaries, turn them into primitive `double`s and finally, we `sum` them.

Comment: Can I use a forEach to extract the element and add the salary of each Item.

Comment: @PhilipPuthenvila, yes, if you wish to simply end up with a stream of `Employee`s, stop at `.map(Map.Entry::getValue)` and then you can `forEach`.

Comment: @Fureeish using entries and then mapping immediately to values is unnecessary. Simpler to just stream the map's values directly. See my answer for example.

Comment: @sprinter good point. I always tend to forget about `keys()` and `values()` methods from `Map`. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using the built in stats collector if you will possibly need other stats in the future.

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics salaryStats = mainMap.values().stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(Employee::getSalary));
```

That way you get sum, count, max, min, average.